# An exercise on derived category in Weibel's book: commuting $\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R$ with $\otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_R$ in a "weird" way

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories

My question is on the following exercise in Weibel's book: Exercise 10.8.3.

**Exercise 10.8.3**: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $C$ a bounded complex of finite $\mathrm{Tor}$-dimension over $R$. Show that there is a natural isomorphism in the derived category $\mathsf{D}(R-\mathrm{Mod})$:
$$
\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B) \otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_R C \cong \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B \otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_R C ).
$$

**How I got stuck**: I feel that the general way to prove such problems is in two steps:

1. *Degenerate* the desired isomorphism to the zeroth degree and prove the zeroth degree version.
2. Use the *composition theorem for derived functors* (i.e. $\mathbf{R}(GF) \cong \mathbf{R}G \circ \mathbf{R}F$) to *upgrade* to the derived version.

At least for most exercises and theorem I have met, the thing works smoothly:

> **Example 1**: To show
> $$
> \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,\mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(B,C)) \cong \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(A \otimes^{\mathbf{L}}_R B, C )  \quad\quad (\star),
> $$
> we first degenerate it to the zeroth degree as
> $$
> \mathrm{Hom}_R(A, \mathrm{Hom}_R(B,C)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_R(A \otimes_R B, C).
> $$
> This is the clear adjoint isomorphism. Then we view both sides as composed functors in $B$. Then *if $A$ is a projective complex and $C$ is an injective complex*, we check the conditions of the composition theorem of derived functors hold. So we upgrade both sides to the derived version. Then we take projective resolution of $A$ and injective resolution of $C$ in general, we have the final isomorphism $(\star)$.

> **Example 2**: We can also prove the Shapiro's lemma in group cohomology by this method, by first degenerate to the canonical isomorphism
> $$
> \mathrm{Hom}_G(\mathbb{Z}, \mathrm{Ind}^G_H(-)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_H(\mathbb{Z}, -)
> $$
> and upgrade it to
> $$
> \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_G(\mathbb{Z}, \mathrm{Ind}^G_H(-)) \cong \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_H(\mathbb{Z}, -),
> $$
> by further noticing $\mathrm{Ind}^G_H(-)$ is an exact functor. Then taking the $n$-th cohomology, we get the Shapiro's lemma.

**But my experience fails** when facing the exercise above, since the isomorphism on the zeroth degree level, i.e. commuting tensor product with Hom in such a weird (for me) way is quite out of reach for me. Yet I have no idea how to tackle in another approach.

---

Similar questions arises when I'm trying to solve the following exercise in Weibel's book:

**Exercise 10.8.4**: Let $f: R \rightarrow S$ is a flat ring homomorphism, and $f^{\ast}$ is the functor sending an $R$-module $A$ to the $S$-module $A \otimes_{R} S$. Now suppose $A$ is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded above complex of finitely generated projective modules. Show that we have a natural isomorphism for every $B$ in $\mathsf{D}^{+}(R-\mathrm{Mod})$:
$$
\mathbf{L}f^{\ast} \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_R(A,B) \rightarrow \mathbf{R}\mathrm{Hom}_S(\mathbf{L}f^{\ast}A, \mathbf{L}f^{\ast} B).
$$

And similar to the previous exercise, I also got stuck at the very first beginning, feeling confused on the degenerated version.

**Or maybe my two-step approach has some hidden troubles that I haven't realized? Or is it quite limited in the application of derived category?**

Quite frustrated! :(

Thank you all for helping, commenting or answering, or even reading such a long post! :)

Comment: I don’t understand derived categories as well as I would like to, but as far as I can tell the second problem has a solution “by hand”, making the complex explicit (I can give you details if you want). The idea is that (rot13) bayl gur cebwrpgvir erfbyhgvba bs N znggref.

Comment: @Aphelli Thank you for your hints! I'm sorry but maybe due to the internet issues or that is a language that I cannot read, I cannot figure out what your last sentence *" The idea is that (rot13) bayl gur cebwrpgvir erfbyhgvba bs N znggref"* means.

Comment: @HetongXu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: I'm clearly missing something, because I don't see why $C$ needs to be "a bounded complex of finite Tor-dimension".  But there is an obvious injection $\operatorname{Hom}(A\to B)\otimes C\to\operatorname{Hom}(A\to B\otimes C)$, based on considering $C$ as the space of constant functions $A\to C$; if $C$ is projective, then I can use the dual basis to write down a right-inverse.  Does this make the level-zero version of your original question more plausible?

Comment: @JacobManaker Thank you! It turns out that requiring $C$ to be finitely generated projective is necessary to make the obvious injection into a bijection. Thank you for pointing out this!  (And thank you for showing me that ROT13 is actually an encryption algorithm. :) )

Comment: I have finally figure out almost everything except for a comment by Jeremy Rickard. I will post an answer to the above two exercises in about two weeks after my qualify exam. Thank you all for your help and sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The underived version of this isomorphism

$$\text{Hom}(A, B) \otimes C \cong \text{Hom}(A, B \otimes C)$$

is false without quite strong hypotheses; you can think of it as trying to commute a limit, namely $\text{Hom}(A, -)$, with a colimit, namely $(-) \otimes C$, and limits and colimits generally don't commute without further hypotheses. For this setup, since the hypotheses are on $C$ I'll give hypotheses on $C$: with no hypotheses on $A, B$ we need $C$ to be finitely generated projective, or equivalently finitely presented flat. I suppose "bounded complex of finite Tor-dimension" is a derived analogue of this but I'm not familiar with the details.

Other sets of hypotheses that make this true are

- $A$ is finitely generated projective
- $A$ is finitely presented and $C$ is flat
- $A$ is projective and $C$ is finitely presented.

See [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/226363/290) for some discussion.

For a counterexample when these hypotheses are dropped take $R = \mathbb{Z}, A = \mathbb{Q}, B = \mathbb{Z}, C = \mathbb{Q}$. Note that neither $A$ nor $C$ are finitely presented.

Comment: A "bounded complex of finite Tor-dimension" is simply one that is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of flat modules. So your counterexample shows that the statement in the exercise is false without some extra hypotheses.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I wonder if it would suffice to ask for a complex quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of finitely generated projective modules. Presumably this has a name but it escapes me.

Comment: That's called "perfect".

Comment: Thank you for your answer (both here and in MO)! I have finished up the proof of the underived version under your three additional hypothesis. To provide references, the proof on the second and the third condition can be found in Bourbaki's *Commutative Algebra*, Chapter I, Section 9. The proof of the first case can be found in Bourbaki's *Algebra*, Chapter II, Section 4, No. 2. Maybe it's worth noting that the proof under the first hypothesis is quite different with the proof under the 2nd or the 3rd hypothesis.

Answer (score 7):

As Qiaochu Yuan shows in his answer, the statement in this exercise is false without extra hypotheses. In fact, it turns out that Weibel knew this.

In [a list of corrections to the 1995 edition](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eweibel/Hbook.errors.edition2.pdf), he includes a correction to this exercise, so that the statement is that there is a natural homomorphism in $D(R)$, which is an isomorphism if either $C$
is a complex of finitely generated projective $R$-modules or else $A$ is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded below chain complex of finitely generated projective $R$-modules.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for providing the errata for Weibel's book, that's very helpful! Yet could you elaborate more on your comment under Yuan Qiaochu's answer, which is *"A 'bounded complex of finite Tor-dimension' is simply one that is quasi-isomorphic to a bounded complex of flat modules."*? I have tried these days but found no clue on this. Or could you provide some references on this? Thank you!

Comment: And it seems that we still need to require $C$ to be a bounded complex (at least bounded above (cochain) complex) to make it possible to take the projective resolution of $C$?

Comment: @HetongXu The [Stacks Project](V) has a thorough discussion of Tor-dimension. See in particular Lemma 15.66.3 for the statement in my comment. This statement also appears in Weibel's book, but only as an exercise (Exercise 10.6.3) and without a proof.

Comment: @HetongXu As I understand the errata, Weibel intended the first sentence of the exercise to remain the same. So yes, $C$ is still a bounded complex of finite Tor-dimension.

Comment: Thank you! I will turn to Stacks Project for it! Thank you so much!

Comment: (Maybe useful for later viewers, the corresponding Stacks Project's link is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0654   .)

Comment: @HetongXu Actually the link I meant was [stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0651](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0651) of which your link is just a part. (I meant to include that in my previous comment, but it looks as though I accidentally typed "V" instead of "Ctrl-V"!)

Comment: Haha, and from this typo I learnt how to insert a link into a comment. :)